# Uncharted - Disable puzzle hints from Sully

Tags: uncharted-3

I started playing the Uncharted series and what I find really annoying, is that whenever there is a puzzle that needs solving, Sully always rushes to give you the solution.

For example, The Chateau puzzle in Uncharted 3.

[image: Drake’s book]

As soon as I enter the puzzle room, Sully says: “Maybe you need to step on the stones in the right order”. It’s not that hard to figure out from the book, but the game doesn’t even give you a chance to figure it out by yourself, and this happens with almost every single puzzle.

Do you know if there’s a way to disable these game hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the very extreme (and unintended) method of turning off the voice volume and turning off subtitles, effectively silencing Sully.

Besides that, there's no way to selectively turn off hints.